# How can I mock the return value of Nodes net library functions?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I have a Node module where I try to connect to a host with:

```
const testConnection = net.createConnection(port, hostname);

testConnection.on('connect', () => {
   // connected
});

testConnection.on('error', (err) => {
   // error
});
```

I am using **Sinon** to test the method like this:

```
sinon.stub(net, 'createConnection', (port, hostname) => {
   return {
      on: (string, cb) => {
         switch(string) {
              case 'connect':
                  return cb;
              case 'error':
                  return cb;
              case 'close':
                  return cb;
            }
        }
    }
});

const testConnection = net.createConnection(10, 'hostname');
testConnection.on('error', () => {
   console.log('here I am');
});
```

But I cannot wrap my head around how I should no stub/mock or fake-call the on-method so it returns an error!

> Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stub `createConnection` return value with a fake EventEmitter instance:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const fakeEE = new EventEmitter();
sinon.stub(net, 'createConnection', (port, hostname) => fakeEE);

// require your code

// emit events
fakeEE.emit('error', new Error('Smth bad happened'));

// observe the result
// e.g. expect(something).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: If I emit an Error, the tests fails because of an Error ;) Is there a way around it?

Comment: @gruberb as the code under test is setting `.on('error',...)` handler, there won't be an error of `Unhandled 'error' event` kind. So it is a way to test what your code doing if a connection emits an error. Or I misunderstood your need?

Answer (score 0):

As `net` is dependency of your module, I would use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to fake that dependency. Works great for us also with ES6 + Babel combo.